# Java Applet Error Launching

Tags: java, web-applications, applet

I've created a small Java Applet to run for a company website. I'm currently using Eclipse for development and I've run into problems while trying to launch the application from the appropriate web page. My employee has placed the correct .JAR file in with the HTML file of the page itself, and is calling the applet with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<applet code=OrderForm.class name=OrderForm archive=OrderForm.jar
    width=700 height=1100 >
    <param name="bgcolor" value="ffffff">
    <param name="fontcolor" value="000000">
    Your browser is not Java enabled.
</applet>



</body>
</html>
```

All this seems correct to me, the JAR file is correctly labeled, and the .class file is correct. When the page opens, I get the message "Error. Click for Details", but when I click the 'X', the page freezes and doesn't show me any error details.

The JAR file was exported using Eclipse and I'm sure that I've included all the necessary files to compile (as it compiles perfectly with the Java Applet Viewer in Eclipse). Here's the applet below, it's simply a testing applet I created because of some past errors I was receiving when trying to run a larger applet on the company website, so this covers the basic functionality of the applet itself, thanks.

```
package OrderForm;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.JButton;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OrderForm extends JApplet {

    private JPanel mainPanel = null;  //  @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="10,10"
    private JLabel titleLabel = null;
    private JLabel customerInfoLabel = null;
    private JLabel distributorLabel = null;
    private JLabel customerNameLabel = null;
    private JLabel existingCustomerLabel = null;
    private JLabel industryLabel = null;
    private JLabel emailAddressLabel = null;
    private JButton testing = null;
    private JTextField text_customerName = null;
    private JTextField text_emailAddress = null;
    private JComboBox distributors = null;
    private JComboBox industries = null;
    private JCheckBox check_existingCustomer = null;
    /**
     * This is the xxx default constructor
     */
    public OrderForm() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes this
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public void init() {
        try 
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    setSize(645, 373);
                    setContentPane(getJContentPane());
                }
            });
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes mainPanel
     * 
     * @return javax.swing.JPanel
     */
    private JPanel getJContentPane() {
        if (mainPanel == null) {
            emailAddressLabel = new JLabel();
            emailAddressLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(164, 226, 137, 16));
            emailAddressLabel.setText("Email Address:");
            industryLabel = new JLabel();
            industryLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(165, 196, 136, 16));
            industryLabel.setText("Industry:");
            existingCustomerLabel = new JLabel();
            existingCustomerLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(165, 165, 136, 16));
            existingCustomerLabel.setText("Existing Customer?:");
            customerNameLabel = new JLabel();
            customerNameLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(166, 134, 135, 16));
            customerNameLabel.setText("Customer Name:");
            distributorLabel = new JLabel();
            distributorLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(165, 105, 136, 16));
            distributorLabel.setText("Distributor:");
            customerInfoLabel = new JLabel();
            customerInfoLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(30, 60, 166, 31));
            customerInfoLabel.setText("Customer Information");
            titleLabel = new JLabel();
            titleLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(180, 15, 286, 40));
            titleLabel.setText("Order Form");
            mainPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.setSize(new Dimension(624, 1055));
            mainPanel.setLayout(null);
            mainPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
            mainPanel.add(titleLabel, null);
            mainPanel.add(customerInfoLabel, null);
            mainPanel.add(distributorLabel, null);
            mainPanel.add(customerNameLabel, null);
            mainPanel.add(existingCustomerLabel, null);
            mainPanel.add(industryLabel, null);
            mainPanel.add(emailAddressLabel, null);
            mainPanel.add(getTesting(), null);
            mainPanel.add(getText_customerName(), null);
            mainPanel.add(getText_emailAddress(), null);
            mainPanel.add(getDistributors(), null);
            mainPanel.add(getIndustries(), null);
            mainPanel.add(getCheck_existingCustomer(), null);
        }
        return mainPanel;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes testing  
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JButton  
     */
    private JButton getTesting() {
        if (testing == null) {
            testing = new JButton();
            testing.setBounds(new Rectangle(225, 285, 181, 61));
            testing.setText("TEST");
            testing.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    String distSelected = (String) distributors.getSelectedItem();
                    String industrySelected = (String) industries.getSelectedItem();

                    if(distSelected.equals("            "))
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Distributor Selected.", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    else if(industrySelected.equals("            "))
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Industry Selected.", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    else if(text_customerName.getText().length() == 0)
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Name Entered.", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    else if(text_emailAddress.getText().length() == 0)
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Email Entered.", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    else
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Entered Successfully", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);



                }
            });
        }
        return testing;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes text_customerName    
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JTextField   
     */
    private JTextField getText_customerName() {
        if (text_customerName == null) {
            text_customerName = new JTextField();
            text_customerName.setBounds(new Rectangle(300, 135, 121, 16));
        }
        return text_customerName;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes text_emailAddress    
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JTextField   
     */
    private JTextField getText_emailAddress() {
        if (text_emailAddress == null) {
            text_emailAddress = new JTextField();
            text_emailAddress.setBounds(new Rectangle(300, 225, 121, 16));
        }
        return text_emailAddress;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes distributors 
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JComboBox    
     */
    private JComboBox getDistributors() {
        if (distributors == null) {
            distributors = new JComboBox();
            distributors.setBounds(new Rectangle(300, 105, 121, 16));

            String[] distributorList = getDistributorList();

            for(String d:distributorList)
                distributors.addItem(d);
        }
        return distributors;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the list of distributors for the drop-down list
     * @return String[] containing the names of all distributors
     */
    private String[] getDistributorList()
    {
        String[] distributors = 
        {       
                "            ",
                "a1envirotech", "Beun-De Ronde B.V.", "Biolab A/S", "BRS", "Camlab Ltd.", "DKSH Australia Pty Ltd.", "DKSH New Zealand Ltd.",
                "DKSH - Malaysia", "DKSH - Philippines", "DKSH - Singapore", "DKSH - Vietnam", "E&C Technology Co., Ltd.", "FKV s.r.l.",
                "G&W Marketing", "LICA United Technology Ltd.", "Mandel Scientific Company Inc.", "Mansci (Aaron Gotway)", "Mansci (Chris Copeland)",
                "Mansci (Jake Bolotin)", "Mansci (Matt Grey)", "Mansci (Wes Floyd)", "Serlabo", "Southern Systems Ltd.", "TM - Autolab",
                "Wirsam Scientific"
        };
        return distributors;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes industries   
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JComboBox    
     */
    private JComboBox getIndustries() {
        if (industries == null) {
            industries = new JComboBox();
            industries.setBounds(new Rectangle(300, 195, 121, 16));

            String[] industryList = getIndustryList();
            for(String i:industryList)
                industries.addItem(i);
        }
        return industries;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the list of industries for the drop-down list
     */
    private String[] getIndustryList()
    {
        String[] industries = 
        {
                "            ", "Commercial Lab", "Environmental", "Food / Wine", "Government", "Marine Lab", 
                "Other", "Petro Chemical", "Power Generation", "Pulp & Paper", "University"
        };
        return industries;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes check_existingCustomer   
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JCheckBox    
     */
    private JCheckBox getCheck_existingCustomer() {
        if (check_existingCustomer == null) {
            check_existingCustomer = new JCheckBox();
            check_existingCustomer.setBounds(new Rectangle(300, 165, 31, 16));
        }
        return check_existingCustomer;
    }

}  //  @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="10,10"
```

Comment: Which browser? The applet tag is deprecated - it's not supported in HTML 5 or XHTML Strict. While this might not be the issue here, it's a good idea to change it to use the correct modern approach. I understand the modern approach uses JNLP and Javascript. However, if that's not compatible with the client system for some reason, you'd probably want to use the object tag or the embed tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your `JApplet` is in the (unconventionally named) `package OrderForm`, but your [`<applet>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html) tag does not reflect this.

Comment: You're right, should I remove the applet from the OrderForm package? (this is the only class file in that package anyways)

Comment: That should work, but using the default package is _not_ recommended. Preferably, add the package name to the `applet` tag's `code` attribute, as shown in the article cited.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. Once again stackoverflow has saved me haha